# fromString in haskell - with checking returned type

Tags: haskell

Is there exists function `fromString` in haskell ?  I am expectning that beside convert from String to `a`, I would be able to check if `a` is Integer or `Boolean`.   Could you  help me ?

Comment: `read`? ... I have some trouble understanding your question - can you add some examples or try to rework it?

Comment: In my mind, this question is asking for a universal `readDyn :: String -> Maybe Dynamic` which is able to read "anything", and let the user test whether the `Dynamic` is of this or that type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`fromString` already exists as a function in the typeclass `IsString`. It's main use is to (with the `-XOverloadedStrings` compile option) allow you to use string literals for all of the different string implementations that Haskell has, e.g. strict/lazy ByteString and strict/lazy Text, but there are other instances, e.g. for urls, file paths, and others.

You mention both *convert* and *check* operations. For conversion I would suggest using `read`. Here is a simple program which converts a string to a Bool:

```
main = do putStr "Enter a boolean:"
          inp <- getLine
          let b = read inp
          if b then putStrLn "You entered True"
               else putStrLn "You entered False"
```

However, if the user does not enter either `True` or `False`, `read` will throw an error. So only use `read` if you know you have valid input or if it is ok to die if the input is invalid.

If you need to check for invalid input, I think the simplest approach is to simply write your own functions - at least for simple types like `Bool` and `Int`:

```
readBool :: String -> Maybe Bool
readBool str | str == "True"  = Just True
             | str == "true"  = Just True
             | str == "False" = Just False
             | str == "false" = Just False
             | otherwise      = Nothing

import Data.Char

readInt :: String -> Maybe Int
readInt str | all isDigit str = Just (read str)
            | otherwise       = Nothing
```

Note that the call to `read` in `readInt` should never fail since we've already verified that the input is valid.

Comment: I would recommend using `Text.Read.readMaybe` instead of re-implementing a parser for every specific type needed.

Comment: For a good example of why you shouldn't reimplement things all the time: your `readInt` parser doesn't accept negative numbers, let alone octal, hex, etc.

Answer (score 2):

Use [`readMaybe`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Text-Read.html#v:readMaybe) from `Text.Read`. It returns `Nothing` if the value couldn't get parsed (aka if `read` would throw an error):

```
import Text.Read (readMaybe)

isInteger :: String -> Bool
isInteger xs = (readMaybe xs :: Maybe Integer) /= Nothing

isBool    :: String -> Bool
isBool    xs = (readMaybe xs :: Maybe Bool)    /= Nothing
```

Of course, if you actually want to *use* the `Integer` or `Bool`, you use `readMaybe`'s result:

```
isPositive :: String -> Either String Bool
isPositive xs = case readMaybe xs :: Maybe Integer of
                  Just n  -> Right (n > 0)
                  Nothing -> Left "Not an Integer"
```

Note that `readMaybe` uses [`reads`](https://hackage.haskell.org/package/base-4.8.2.0/docs/Prelude.html#v:reads), which is available in the Prelude. I suggest you to re-implement `readMaybe` with `reads` if you want to know how `read` and the `Read` instances work.

Answer (score 0):

Use `read`:

```
λ> :t read
read :: Read a => String -> a
λ> read "42" :: Int
42
λ> read "True" :: Bool
True
λ> read "\"a string\"" :: String
"a string"
λ> read "[1,2,3]" :: [Int]
[1,2,3]
```

However, I don't recommend `read` unless you can check that your input is valid because `read` returns an error if the given string could not be parsed, instead of `Nothing`. Try implementing your own function instead (using monads like `Maybe` or `Either` preferably).